# Service is calling actual class instead of mocked class. Junit4 and Jmock

Tags: java, junit4, jmock

I have checked all the existing stack overflow questions on this. But I couldn't find a proper solution.

```
public class TestAuthenticate {
private RestService rs;
private String token_actual = token1;
private Mockery context;
private Authenticate authenticate_object;


@Before
public void setup(){
context = new JUnit4Mockery() {{
    setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
}}; 

rs = new RestService();
}

@Test
public final void testAuthenticate() {

    authenticate_object = context.mock(Authenticate.class);

    context.checking(new Expectations() {
        {
            oneOf(authenticate_object).authenticate_method("username", "password");
            will(returnValue(token1));
        }
     });
    String token = rs.authenticate("username", "password");
    System.out.println(token);

    assertEquals(token_actual, token);
    context.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

}

This is calling actual authenticate method instead of mock authenticate class. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
public class RestService {
public string authenticate(String user, String pass){
Authenticate auth = new Authenticate();
String res = auth.authenticate(user,pass);
}
return res;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you're passing the `authenticate` object to anything. How is the `RestService` supposed to get it?

Comment: Please see my updated code. Rest service has authenticate method that invokes the Authenticate object

Comment: No...you're *instantiating* a new `Authenticate` every time that method is invoked.  I wonder if JMock has something equivalent to Mockito in which one can actually mock out newed calls.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use some form of Dependency Injection to inject the mock AuthenticationService into RestService.  Try rewriting your RestService like,

```
public class RestService {
    private final AuthenticateService auth;
    public RestService(AuthenticateService auth) {
       this.auth = auth;
    } 
    public string authenticate(String user, String pass){
        return auth.authenticate(user,pass);
    }
}
```

And then in your test do

```
 rs = new RestService(authenticate_object);
```

Comment: I did this but I have 7 methods and I cannot write 7 constructors. Also in every method, token goes as a parameter. So I have to call authenticate in each and every method again. Is there any other solution?